# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.1.0"

Tags: wordpress, pdf-generation, wordpress-plugin-creation, wpforms

I am facing an issue with my client's WordPress website. I am using a plugin fluent forms pdf generator but as I go to download the pdf this error comes up

"Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.1.0".
There has been a critical error on this website."

I am unable to resolve this. Anyone here who can resolve this error for me. It will be appreciated.

Comment: Same here but with this version: `Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".` First time i see this

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this issue? Have you contacted technical support?